# Determining type of NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios

I am trying to determine the type of NSManagedObject I am dealing with.
I do it in the following way:

```
NSManagedObject* object;

if ([[object entity].name isEqualToString:@"Folders"]){

  Folders* folderObject = object;

}else if ([[object entity].name isEqualToString:@"AllFiles"]){

    AllFiles* fileObject = object; 
}
```

This method works, however i get a yellow error:
incompatible pointer types initialising "AllFiles" with an expression of NSManagedObject. 
allFiles and Folders are subclasses of NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "yellow error", but a warning :-)

You just have to cast the NSManagedObject to the right class to suppress the warning:

```
if ([[[object entity] name] isEqualToString:@"Folders"]) {
    Folders *folderObject = (Folder *)object;
}
else if ([[[object entity] name] isEqualToString:@"AllFiles"]) {
    AllFiles *fioleObject = (AllFiles *)object;
}
```

The debugger checks the object type and informs you that there is a mismatch. This **could** produce crashes. Since you know that the objects are subclasses of `NSManagedObject` (the debugger doesn't) you can cast the object type to tell the debugger that all's fine.